# Node-RED or Webhook action not working after rule on Watson IoT Platform

Tags: raspberry-pi3, node-red, watson, watson-iot

I'm currently using Watson IoT Platform to collect datas from my Raspberry Pi. On the Pi, I've installed Node-RED that exposes an HTTP POST endpoint (/command).

I created a rule on Watson IoT Platform based on a threshold and three actions if the rule is activated:

- the first one is a Node-RED action invoking the Node-RED node on my
  Raspberry Pi
- the second one is a Webhook action invoking the Node-RED
  node on my Raspberry pi
- the third one is an IFTTT action invoking the
  Webhook channel that invokes the Node-RED node on my Raspberry pi

The first two actions are not working while the third one correctly forwards the HTTP POST request.

What is wrong with the first two actions? Is there a way to debug the HTTP request? Is it just a matter of reachability of my Raspberry Pi from Watson?

Thanks,

Diego

Comment: Is your pi (and Node-RED) exposed to the internet, via port forwarding or a reverse proxy?

Comment: Hi @hardillb, yes I've been testing the endpoint until now using https://www.hurl.it/ . I have a static public IP as well.

Comment: So, it works if you call your /command from something else (hurl.it), but doesn't from Rules.  And it never worked, or worked and then stopped? If it stopped working and you made no changes, probably someone needs to look in the backed logs.